# what is the default media player in android?How we can make url to play video in default player of android?

Tags: android, html, media-player

I understand that all Android phones will have the WebKit browser Application. Is there a default Media Player? How we can make while clicking in url to play video in default player of android?is there any way to embedded code to play in android device default player?

Answer (score 0):

Android Application SDK has MediaPlayer class for multimedia playback use case. You can directly use this class or can use VdeoView class.

Can refer to VideoView usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6977382/videoview-in-eclipse-not-playing-on-phone/6977770#6977770).

Shash

Comment: Thanks shash .... but just i want to know how to play through html? like mobile youtube website.

Answer (score 0):

just a note. If it is a Youtube video, the browser as it is already automatically detects that and offers the user to open the video in Youtube, or other video player the user might have installed.

Comment: from m.youtube.com if i click the link it works exactly. but if i put the same code(a href link) in a html page and if i tried to access that its not working.

Comment: Another one think my aim is not to play the youtube video. My aim is to play my own video.